# when i try to run solidity-coverage with truffle run coverage then I got this error

Tags: code-coverage, solidity, truffle

I try to run solidity coverage for testing test case and its coverage but when I run coverage command its give error like this : -
command used (truffle run coverage)

Using Truffle library from local node_modules.

> solidity-coverage cleaning up, shutting down ganache server
> UnhandledRejections detected
> Promise {
>  TypeError: Cannot read private member from an object whose class did not declare it
> at __classPrivateFieldGet (C:\Users\RahulMuwal\Downloads\smartcontract (2)\smartcontract\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\ganache\dist\node\webpack:\Ganache\core\lib\src\server.js:10:94)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

solidity-coverage doesn't work well with ganache 7, which is packaged in latest Truffle 5.4.x.

To resolve:

1. `yarn add -D ganache@6.12.2` (or `npm install --save-dev ganache@6.12.2`)
2. Create a file called `.solcover.js` in your working directory and add this content (or modify the existing content to include):

   ```js
   module.exports = {
     client: require('ganache-cli'),
   };
   ```

More info can be found [here](https://github.com/sc-forks/solidity-coverage/issues/696).

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm this is happening with brownie as well

The coverage command just hangs out and never ends
lowering it to ganache 6 (ganache-cli) works

Mentioning this as I wasted many hours trying to figure this one out and hopefully this saves someone the misery